# Pass optional parameters to Laravel Form

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

This is an excerpt from my `partials/textfield.blade.php` snippet:

```
{{ Form::text('mylabel', 'mytext', ['class' =>'form-control']) }}
```

I know that it's possible to include this snippet and pass some variables to it:

```
@INCLUDE('partials/textfield', ['required' => 'required', 'autofocus' => 'autofocus'])
```

I want to be able to call the snippet with **optional** parameters for `required`, `autofocus`and `readonly`.

My question now is: How can I pass these variables to the form element?

I tried:

```
{{ Form::text('label',null,
    [
    'class' =>'form-control', 
    'required'  => (isset($required)  ? $required  : 'false'),
    'readonly'  => (isset($readonly)  ? $readonly  : 'false'), 
    'autofocus' => (isset($autofocus) ? $autofocus : 'false') 
    ])
}}
```

This leads to HTML code like `... readonly="false"...`. The presence of `readonly`, however, leads internet browsers to render the fields as readonly.

Replacing `'false'`with `''`doesn't help either. Does anyone know, how to pass these optional parameters to the snippet instead?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{!! Form::input('text', 'email', null, [$required ? 'required' : '', $readonly ? 'readonly' : '', $autofocus? 'autofocus' : '']) !!}
```

Had to change my answer a bit. I'm used to kris/laravel-form-builder. I tried it, should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ Form::text('label',null,
    [
    'class' =>'form-control', 
    'required'  => (isset($required)  ? 'true'  : 'false'),
    'readonly'  => (isset($readonly)  ? 'true'  : 'false'), 
    'autofocus' => (isset($autofocus) ? 'true' : 'false') 
    ])
}}
```

You can set these values to true or false rather.

You will achieve the results.

another way is to

```
@INCLUDE('partials/textfield', [ 'options' => [   'class' =>'form-control', 'required' => 'required', 'autofocus' => 'autofocus']]);
```

Now you can simply

```
{{ Form::text('label',null,
    $options
    )
}}
```

by this way you dont have to check each and every field.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, none of the approaches works for me. The first one leads to `required="false"`, which is rendered to a required field (tested on Windows 10 with IE11, Firefox and Chrome). The second approach leads to an error ("Array to String conversion"). :-(

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. However, I found a solution (see other answer).